# Magento Update - "CONNECT ERROR: Failed to open file"

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to update Magento 1.8.1 store to 1.9.38.

The process end in error with the following message:

```
CONNECT ERROR: Failed to open file C:/MagentoDir\downloader\.cache\community\Interface_Adminhtml_Default-1.9.3.8\app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/order/invoice/create/items/renderer
Failed to open file C:/MagentoDir\downloader\.cache\community\Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default-1.9.3.8\app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/options/conf
```

Any idea on possible causes?

I'm not able to update the Store due this error and, I suppose due the first error, I'm not able to login to admin panel.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error when trying to upgrade from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.8 (on windows 10) Then when trying to login on the admin panel I get this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function setActive() on boolean in C:\wamp64\www\magento-test\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Controller\Action.php on line 111` php version 5.6.31